# Change log level ros2_control hardware interface

Tags: ros2, ros2-control

I use ros2_control with my own hardware interface. In this interface, I log some stuff in DEBUG. I would like to set log level to DEBUG in my launch file so that I can see these logs.

In other words, how can I set it for a controller launched using the spawner executable from controller_manager package ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `--ros-args --log-level DEBUG` when you start the Controller Manager node? If you are using a launch file, it would mean that you would need to add `arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', 'DEBUG']` to the Controller Manager Node. This should enable the Controller Manager node to log in DEBUG mode.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct !! Just found it by myself and was editing my post. Thanks a lot for your answer.